# Setting array with for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

In my code i want to keep track of the order of buttons pressed by using an array (order is the array name), and then each time a button is pressed that button will be recorded inside the array. This will be done by having booleans for certain buttons, if a button is pressed the boolean is true and from there if the boolean is true it will set the next open spot in the order array to that key. Here is how it is done so far:

```
private boolean bird = false;
private boolean ox = false;
private boolean dog = false;
String[] order = new String[10];

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for(int i=0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_T) bird = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_U) ox = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_G) dog = true;
        }
}
    public void order(){
       if(bird){
        for(int x=0; x < 10; x++){
            if(order[x] == null) order[x] = "bird";
            bird = false;
        }
    }
       if(ox){
        for(int x=0; x < 10; x++){
            if(order[x] == null) order[x] = "ox";
            ox = false;
        }
    }
       if(dog){
        for(int x=0; x < 10; x++){
            if(order[x] == null) order[x] = "dog";
            dog = false;
        }
    }
}
```

*please note that the animals here represent the keys*

the problem here is that when i check to see what each index of the array is set to it gives me only one of the keys. 
example; i press t and all the orders (0,1,2) are bird. I know that this is because the code goes through all the orders to see if they are null which in the beginning they are, and then it sets those null orders to the word. After that none of the orders are null. 
What I am asking is how do i make it so the for loop stops after it sets one of index's to a word? i tried  'break' but it didn't work, i also looked hopelessly on the internet. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` is the way to go exit a for-loop. Did you think of adding brackets to the if-statement? By the way you can move the `animal=false;` lines out of each for-loop:

```
if(dog){
    for(int x=0; x < 10; x++){
        if(order[x] == null) {
            order[x] = "dog";
            break;
        }
    }
    dog = false;
}
```

But here is cleaner way to do what you want, without all the for-loops:

```
int index = 0;
String[] order = new String[10];

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for(int i=0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
           if(key == KeyEvent.VK_T) order[index++] = "bird";
           if(key == KeyEvent.VK_U) order[index++] = "ox";
           if(key == KeyEvent.VK_G) order[index++] = "dog";
        }
    }
}
```

Or even better, with a list, so you are not limited to 10 inputs:

```
List<String> order = new ArrayList<String>();

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    for(GameObject tempObject : handler.object){
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){
           if(key == KeyEvent.VK_T) order.add("bird");
           if(key == KeyEvent.VK_U) order.add("ox");
           if(key == KeyEvent.VK_G) order.add("dog");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with using break; is that it only lets the first order be set, using a key after that makes no difference. EDIT: okay so i played around with it and put break bird and ox but not dog, and when i do that if i press bird the first one is bird, if i press ox nothing happens, and when i press dog the second and third order become dog. I'm not sure why this occurs but thought id share.

Comment: The `break;` statements should be inside bracketed if statements where you change the value @GMagician as of right now i cant tell if thats what youve done but that behavior sounds odd.

Comment: 'code' if(bird){
   for(int x=0; x < 10; x++){
    if(order[x] == null) order[x] = "bird";
    break;
   }
   bird = false;
  } 'code'                                                                                                 i put the break within the { } after the if statement and i thought that was weird behavior as well. EDIT: thanks that way worked!